# Maintaining document Heading hierarchy python-docx

Tags: python, django, python-docx

I am developing algorithms for extracting sections of a Docx file while maintaining document structure
I managed to get headings but How do I go about getting the data between headers and maintain header hierarchy: This is what I have done so far.

**Sample Code :**

```
from docx import Document
document=Document('headerEX.docx')
paragraphs=document.paragraphs
 def iter_headings(paragraphs):
      for paragraph in paragraphs:
          if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
                yield paragraph

for heading in iter_headings(document.paragraphs):
   print (heading.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you a start:

```
sections = []
section_heading = None
section_paragraphs = []
for paragraph in paragraph:
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
        section = {
            'heading': section_heading,
            'paragraphs': section_paragraphs
        }
        sections.append(section)
        section_heading = paragraph.text
        section_paragraphs = []
        continue
    section_paragraphs.append(paragraph)

for section in sections:
    print(section['heading'])
    for paragraph in section['paragraphs']:
        print(paragraph.text)
```

As written, this may give you an empty section extract as the first one, and will not capture the last section. I leave those details to you as an exercise to strengthen your coding skills :)